# Simulate Click on Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome-extension, click, screen, simulate, chromebook

I am trying to create a Chromebook application that can map keyboard input to a screen click. Is there an API that enables you to simulate a click on your Chromebook in a desired position?

Example: A user presses 'A' on the keyboard and then the app simulates a screen click in the position 100(x), 120(y).

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: Simulate a mouse click on a Chromebook using Javascript.

Comment: ..to do what? What's the goal of this clicking?

Comment: Enable users to play multi-touch Android games such as Minecraft Pocket Edition using the keyboard. If I could map keys like WASD to screen clicks, games like MCPE would be playable. Minecraft can run on the chromebook, but if it's not touch screen it can be difficult to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is basically no.

There is [no API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index) to simulate input in other apps (such as your example). You would also not be able to capture keyboard outside very limited "global shortcut" input while another app is focused.

Comment: I kind of figured that. Thanks!